# Calling Google oauth using jersey client

Tags: java, oauth, jersey

I'm calling the Google oauth for token using the Jersey client as shown below.

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
Client client = Client.create(config);
WebResource webResource = client.resource(UriBuilder.fromUri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token").build());
MultivaluedMap formData = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
formData.add("code", request.getParameter("code"));
formData.add("client_id", Global.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID);
formData.add("redirect_uri", Global.GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URL);
formData.add("client_secret", Global.GOOGLE_SECRET);
formData.add("grant_type", "authorization_code");
ClientResponse response1 = webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE).post(ClientResponse.class, formData);
System.out.println(response1.getEntity(String.class));
System.out.println(response1.getClass().getName());
```

Response I get

> {   "access_token" :
>   "ya29.nQCXFIhTs8s-SQKON6NjPv7wkBcJxlasdlkjsdsklsGuzMMqyDz3XpkNLT",
>   "token_type" : "Bearer",   "expires_in" : 3599,   "id_token" :
>   "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjdkZGQwOGEwM2IyNWQwZjVhMDllMjNiMmJlMTBkZDIyODQyYTg1NjkifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJhY2NvdW50csdlksjdsdkljdslkjdsdslkjdjsdkljjsldkjsdj987230iOiJwcmVtMXByZUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJhdF9oYXNoIjoiMmt2RlZ1RUpTMGp4UWlIUDgtckVuZyIsImVtYWlsX3ZlcmlmaWVkIjp0cnVlLCJhdWQiOiI1OTQ5NTUyODE4ODYtYnFyMGRibWRyYWJxYW9ubWhlaXFrMHNrZGRmNWFsazUuYXBwcy5nb29nbGV1c2VyY29udGVudC5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE0MTMyMTQ4ODIsImV4cCI6MTQxMzIxODc4Mn0.pc2Snmb4pRF_TqylBuEpz0oBoWZsIq-_r_sqLS06E6DJKgSawWCg_3vqtI72GvWno0J8UghZka6rpaoAFo5RZlxNxLDs4GV5rZqdodNgbKjEO-5MrpGZWUOM7SNoYooASesmTtbamDoCf6G74MSKW5XKaVwdvFEUsSBz5NuavNU"}

How can I get the id_token from the response and get the actual values in the response.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution for what you have so far implemented is to use the JSONSerializer to get the JSONObject representation of the string response.  The code could look similar to this:

```
JSONObject jsonOutput = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON( response.getEntity(String.class) ); 
String access_token = jsonOutput.getString("access_token");
String id_token = jsonOutput.getString("id_token");
```

I would recommend however using the google java client for making the call:  https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2

Using the GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest class you can get back a GoogleResponseToken directly without worrying about the JSON.  The example is here: http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.18.0-rc/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.html

The code is as simple as this (taken directly from link):

```
  GoogleTokenResponse response =
      new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(),
          "812741506391.apps.googleusercontent.com", "{client_secret}",
          "4/P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp7", "https://oauth2-login-demo.appspot.com/code")
          .execute();
  System.out.println("Access token: " + response.getAccessToken());
  System.out.println("Id token: " + response.getIdToken());
```